# -webkit-transform flicker in ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad

```
$('#pageViewContainer').css({"transform": "scale(" + (tool.scalefactor) + ")",'-webkit-perspective': 1000,'-webkit-backface-visibility': 'hidden'});
```

I am using above code to apply transform property in ipad but while doing that my application crash in ipad it's working fine in desktop is their any other way to do these

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
       backface-visibility:hidden;
```